# What is the correct way of generating a base-10 naming scheme (i.e. generating polygon names)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list or dictionary of [polygon names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polygons), so that I can generate a name for any given number of sides, e.g. if the input is 18, then the output would be "octadecagon"
I feel like there should be a simple way to do this but I'm not sure how

I thought that maybe I could brute force it by using integer division and a remainder, but that seemed too tedious and ineffective

Answer (score 1):

Just use a dictionary:

```
names = {3: 'triangle', 4: 'rectangle', 18: 'octadecagon'}
```

You can define a `name()` function that uses it:

```
def name(num):
    return names[num]
```

or just use `names[number]` to get the name of the shape you want.

Comment: But the problem is that I would need to manually make 100000 dictionary entries, what I want to do is basically find a simple way to do that. The point of my program is to generate a polygon for any number of sides given (from 3-100000)

Comment: You might be able to come up with a function that maps out the patterns in naming, but you're really better off just copy-pasting a list into a document and then reading it to a dictionary. I'm not sure if there's even a word for a 10345-sided polygon. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polygons

Comment: That would be a "myriatrihectatetracontakaipentagon", apparently.  Of course, that would be *utterly useless* for a program to output, because who's going to be able to understand it?  "10345-gon" would probably be the most readable format.

Comment: That name is actually quite amusing. Also of note is the fact that monogons and digons exist, meaning that for a complete list you'd have to start at 1